# Increase padding on X elements when Y element's width decreases

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, padding

The `body` element by default is of course taking up `100%` width so when the browser window is resized this width in pixels will obviously decrease. For every pixel the `body` width is decreased I want to increase the padding of a group of elements ( `header`, `main`, and `footer` ) by 1 pixel. Not sure where to start. Here is a basic set up:

```js
function start() {
  //code here..
}

start();
```

```css
@import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body, header, main, footer {
  padding: 1%;
}
header, main, footer {
  height: 33.333%;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ddd;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <p>When this snippet is made <b>Full page</b>.</p>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div>
    <p>And the browser window width is <i>decreased</i>.</p>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div>
    <p>The padding on these rectangles should <i>increase</i>.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

When the browser window is resized and `body` width **decreased** I want the padding value on `header`, `width`, and `height` to **increase** proportionately.

I originally tried accomplishing this without JavaScript utilizing CSS [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) units. That did not work out very well.

PS: *I'm trying not to use Jquery.*

---

**EDIT:** I just realized this but it might be worth pointing out that the default padding behavior is to *decrease* in value as the containing elements width decreases. As both top *&* bottom and left *&* right `padding` is calculated by the containers **width** as can be seen when my snippet is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
padding: 0 calc( 500px - 50vw );
```

This works, but only for a limited range of viewport sizes (500px - 1000px).

The issue with doing the calculation in just CSS is that there will have to be a defined upper and lower bound, because viewports could in theory be thousands of pixels wide and it will have exhausted the amount of padding available to it at some point.

My code works by setting the upper limit with the value of `500px`, so 1000px total when applied to left and right, and then the lower limit is the half of that by the value of `50vw`, or in other words 50%. If you play with these values you can hopefully align the upper and lower bounds to suit your needs.

http://codepen.io/zepha/pen/QpMRYQ

Comment: This is interesting. Doing some experiments with this. Funny cause something like this was my first instinct but I kept failing.

Comment: This actually works brilliantly with lots of tweaking and changing pixel units to `vh`. `padding: calc( 80vh - 120vw )` did it for me. Thank you.